# JPA OneToMany duplicate child

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

I am trying to implement a `OneToMany` relationship and having a really hard time in selecting the child records.

For example: `Parent` P1 has 3 `Child` entities and `Parent` P2 has 2 `Child` entities, say

- P1 has C1,C2,C3
- P2 has C4,C6

But code below returns

- P1 has C1,C1,C1
- P2 has C1,C1

Interestingly the number of child entities is correct, but the data itself is just duplicate of the first record. I tried setting distinct but that doesn't seem to help.

```
 CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = db2EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
 CriteriaQuery<Parent> searchQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Parent.class);
 Root<Parent> aRoot = searchQuery.from(Parent.class);

 //Constructing list of parameters
 List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

 //Adding predicates in case of parameter not being null
 predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(aRoot.get("a"), "A"));
 predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(aRoot.get("b"), "B"));
 predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(aRoot.get("c"), "C"));

 //query itself
 searchQuery.select(aRoot).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})).distinct(true);

 TypedQuery<Parent> query = db2EntityManager.createQuery(searchQuery);
 parentEntities = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: We need to know what do you persist? And what is in the database eventually? I think `distinct` has nothing to do with your problem. Why are those predicates, please tell more detailed?

Comment: I am trying to read a oneToMany data and not storing anything. So parent entity P and child entity C shares a composite keys A,B,C,D. Predicates are the where condition on P. Basically i am querying P with A,B,C id values and trying to get  A.C child records.

Comment: Below is a simplified version of the "child query" form the log.
select child.D, child.A, child.B, child.C, child.D, child.A, child.B, child.C, child.D, child.A, child.B,child.C ,  child.X, child.Y, child.Z, from, MAIN.CHILD child 
where child.D=? and child.A=?  and child.B=?  and child.C=?

Comment: As you can see the ID's are present THRICE in the query. PLease tell me what am i doing wrong. Other than the repeating ID's the binding  is correct. I think the query is executing like its supposed to but  its going somewhere wrong while assigning it to the child Set in the Parent.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with the Primary Key in the Child entity. The composite key was not returning unique records.